# How to Check values using a form javascript

Tags: javascript

I built a client's class and also made a form. I try to check the entries through the form I created but as soon as I click on `SUBMIT` nothing happens and the function seems to not send me an `ALERT` message telling me if the name is good or not someone knows maybe why it is not good and I also check them by the class set

```
    class Client{
        constructor(full_name,id_person,gender,age){
            this.setFull_name = full_name;
            this.setId_person = id_person;
            this.setGender = gender;
            this.setAge = age;
        }
        get getFull_name(){
            return this.full_name
        }
        set setFull_name(full_name){
            this.full_name = full_name.test(/^[A-Za-z]{3,}$/)[0]
        }
        get getId_person(){
            return this.id_person
        }
        set setId_person(id_person){
            if(id_person > 0)
                this.id_person = id_person
        }
        get getGender(){
            return this.gender
        }
        set setGender(gender){
            this.gender = gender
        }
        get getAge(){
            return this.age
        }
        set setAge(age){
            if(age >=18)
                this.age = age
        }
        toString(){
                return "<font size='5'> The full name is: ["+this.full_name+"]"
                   + " and the ID is: ["+this.id_person+"] "
                   + " and the gender is: ["+this.gender+"] and the age is ["+this.age+"]"
            }
    }
    function check(form){
        var checkName = document.getElementById("fullName").value;
        //alert(fullName.value)
        if(!(checkName.test(form.fullName.value))){
            alert("the full name is not good") //need fix
        }
        else{
            return true
            alert("the name is good")
        }
    }


     <form id="form" name="form" onsubmit="return check(form) && false;">
        <h2>Client</h2>
        <label>full name</label>
        <input type="text" name="fullName" id="fullName" placeholder="full name"><br>

        <label>ID</label>
        <input type="text" name="id_person" id="id_person" placeholder="ID"><br>
        
        <label>gender</label>
        <input type="text" name="gender" id="gender" placeholder="gender"><br>
        
        <label>age</label>
        <input type="text" name="age" id="age" placeholder="age"><br>
        
         <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="sumbit">
    </form>
```

Comment: Have you checked your console (web inspector) to see if any errors are popping up?

Comment: @george-ak The problem is `test` method that is not for `string type`. The test method is active only for `RegExp`

Comment: @Alireza Ahmadi yes, have an error in the consoles in my ddd box and that's what I get
https://i.imagesup.co/images2/8a58ddb032711cbe6751b4b301e9445883097426.png

Comment: OK. Did you get your answer? If yes I put it as a `Answer` to better use of everybody

Comment: no I dont know what is the problem

Comment: @Georgeak change `this.full_name = full_name.test(/^[A-Za-z]{3,}$/)[0]` to `this.full_name = /^[A-Za-z]{3,}$/.test(full_name)`

Comment: I told you, you may not use `test` method for `string` if you want to use `test` method you must use `RegExp` see [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_test.asp)

Comment: @SagarV It still does not work The alert message does not reach me

Comment: You made the same mistake on multiple places